# How to find if numbers in the array are in a consecutive order. Number must be 3 or more numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and and I want to know if the values are in a consecutive order. I would like to be consecutive 3 numbers or more. If the numbers are 3 or more numbers in a consecutive order, then a discount to be applied. I am providing some examples that it makes it clear what I want to achieve.

```
["1", "2", "3"] -> OK
["5", "6", "7"] -> OK
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"] -> OK
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] -> OK
["1", "2", "3","4","5"] - > OK
["1", "2"] -> NOT OK
["4", "7"] -> NOT OK
["1", "2", "4"] -> NOT OK
["1", "2", "7"] -> NOT OK

let customNumbersArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",];

customNumbersArray.forEach(num => {
if(num == consecutive) {
// ???
} else {
// ???
}
})
```

Comment: why are numbers not numbers?

Comment: I parseInt(num) after

Comment: Seems like a straight forward simple task. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Just go through the array and check each element against its predecessor:

```js
const data = [
    ["1", "2", "3"],
    ["5", "6", "7"],
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    ["1", "2", "3","4","5"],
    ["1", "2"],
    ["4", "7"],
    ["1", "2", "4"],
    ["1", "2", "7"],
  ]
  const isConsecutive = (nums) => nums.length >= 3 && nums.every((n,i) => i === 0 || n - nums[i-1] === 1)
  data.forEach(d => console.log(JSON.stringify(d), isConsecutive(d)))
```